# "Resource not found for the segment *publisherguid*" in XMLHTTP query to create solution in the CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, odata, dynamics-365

I'm trying to create a solution in the CRM with javascript.
My code is a webresource that I get through a Ribbon I created with "Ribbon Workbench 2016". These things work very good, but when I try to pass the data I get from user ( from a form ) to the CRM, I get the error in the title.

At first I thought the problem was that the guid was all in lower case, so I converted it in upper case. Nothing changed. 
Then I tried using the friendlyname of the publisher instead of the guid. 
Nothing changed. 
Al last, I was frustrated, so I used an empty string, and the error changed from the one in the title, to "*linkPath should have 2 segments*". Guess it was a progress...but still have no idea what the real error might be.

What am I doing wrong? Is it right to treat the solution as an entity an create it that way? Is there a better way?

PS: The query was generated with CRM Rest Builder

```
var entity = {};
entity.friendlyname = $("#solutionForm").dxForm("instance").getEditor("Friendly name").option("value");
entity.uniquename = $("#solutionForm").dxForm("instance").getEditor("Unique name").option("value");
entity.version = $("#solutionForm").dxForm("instance").getEditor("Version").option("value");
entity["publisherid@odata.bind"] = keyValueContainerForPublishers[($("#solutionForm").dxForm("instance").getEditor("Publisher").option("value"))]; //contains guid of selected publisher
entity["configurationpageid@odata.bind"] = "";
entity.description = $("#solutionForm").dxForm("instance").getEditor("Description").option("value");
entity.solutionid = newGuid(); //create unique guid
entity.solutionpackageversion = null;
entity.solutiontype = 0;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", window.parent.opener.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/solutions", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState === 4) {
         req.onreadystatechange = null;
         if (this.status === 204) {
             var uri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
             var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
             var matches = regExp.exec(uri);
             var newEntityId = matches[1];
         } else {
             window.parent.opener.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
         }
      }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

Comment: If it’s working for hard coded values but failing for parameters, verify the values getting passed as parameter by debugging the code to see the format difference. Would like to see the value of JSON.stringify(entity)

Comment: It was not working with either of them ( parameters and hardcoded values ). The problem was in the publisher writteng wrong. I wrote it as Ankuser suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55534462/8318222 and it worked very well. 
Thank you for your reply

Comment: I know, that’s why I asked the “entity” object value.. not sure what’s coming out of “keyValueContainerForPublishers”..

Comment: oh my bad
"keyValueContainerForPublishers" contains json (friendlyname:publisherid) taken from CRM. 
I use friendlyname to populate the dxSelectBox, and the publisherid to create the solution after the user choose the publisher from the dxSelectBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright below Webapi query I tried for creating solutiona and it did worked form me.

Few points to take care of

1. version should be someting like 1.0 or 2.0 or so. only 1 or 2 will not work
2. Publisher, If you compare your code and my code it should be "publishers" and not "publisher"
3. SolutionID you don't have to mention it will automatically create
4. I did not used configuraitonPageID and solutionPackageVersion for now.

Taking care of above things did created a solution for me.

```
var entity = {};
entity.friendlyname = "Test solution from WebAPI";
entity.uniquename = "TestSolutionFromWebAPI";
entity.version = "1.0";
entity["publisherid@odata.bind"] = "/publishers(6007BA03-EE7A-4CA1-A146-7EB0044E504F)";
entity.description = "This is test solution form webapi";
entity.solutiontype = 0;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/solutions", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            var uri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
            var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
            var matches = regExp.exec(uri);
            var newEntityId = matches[1];
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

Comment: Sorry me for late response. Your code worked perfectly. 
The problem was in the publisher. I was missing this 
"/publishers(MYGUID)".

Thank you very much!

PS: Do you have any idea on why the publisher should be written with "/publishers(MYGUID)" instead of only write MYGUID? If you have any documentation to share to me, it would be grate, curious to understand well the problem

Comment: @E.Peracchia [Publisher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/publisher?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) is an entity that has an one to many relationship with the [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/solution?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) entity. Thus, if you want to query for solutions and get the value of the publisher lookup you have to query it like you would for any other lookup, i.e., /EntityPluralName(RecordId).